# enum image resources in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

is there a way to enum programmatically all image resources in a folder?

I want to automate animation images sequence creation process and load images like this:

```
var images = EnumResouceImages("Images/");
foreach(imgPath in images)
    UIImage myImg = UIImage.FromFile(imgPath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know your application's root directory, e.g. by calling `NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl.Path`, you can do this using the `System.IO` types that the base class library (BCL) provides.

E.g. this code:

```
foreach (var filename in Directory.EnumerateFiles (Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundleUrl.Path, "Images"), "*.png"))
    Console.WriteLine (filename);
```

will print every `.png` file located in your application's `Images/` directory.

You can change the filter (e.g. for jpegs or other formats), the directory name (`Images`) or the processing (`Console.WriteLine`) with your own logic.